# How print name of site or lable

Tags: php, web, label, feed

I have a WordPress plugin for show rss feed (Super rss reader)
I want it show name of sites feed, in coding i think its names label,
I find below code in Plugin:

```html
// Display the feed items
echo '<div class="srr-item ' . (($j%2 == 0) ? 'even' : 'odd') . '">';
echo '<div class="srr-title"><li><a href="' . $link . '"' . $newtab . ' title="Posted on ' . $date . '">' . $title . '</a></li></div>';
echo '<div class="srr-meta">';
```

What code i should add to this code for echo/print name of feed website?

The full code of plugin is below:

```html
<?php
/*
Plugin Name: Super RSS Reader
Plugin URI: http://www.aakashweb.com/wordpress-plugins/super-rss-reader/
Author URI: http://www.aakashweb.com/
Description: Super RSS Reader is jQuery based RSS reader widget, which displays the RSS feeds in the widget in an attractive way. It uses the jQuery easy ticker plugin to add a news ticker like effect to the RSS feeds. Multiple RSS feeds can be added for a single widget and they get separated in tabs. <a href="http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=02aOG_-98Tg" target="_blank" title="Super RSS Reader demo video">Check out the demo video</a>.
Author: Aakash Chakravarthy
Version: 2.5
*/

if(!defined('WP_CONTENT_URL')) {
 $srr_url = get_option('siteurl') . '/wp-content/plugins/' . plugin_basename(dirname(__FILE__)).'/';
}else{
 $srr_url = WP_CONTENT_URL . '/plugins/' . plugin_basename(dirname(__FILE__)) . '/';
}

define('SRR_VERSION', '2.5');
define('SRR_AUTHOR', 'Aakash Chakravarthy');
define('SRR_URL', $srr_url);

## Include the required scripts
function srr_public_scripts(){
 // jQuery
    wp_enqueue_script('jquery');
 
 // Super RSS Reader JS and CSS
 wp_register_script('super-rss-reader-js', SRR_URL . 'public/srr-js.js');
 wp_enqueue_script(array('jquery', 'super-rss-reader-js'));
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'srr_public_scripts');

## Include the required styles
function srr_public_styles(){
 wp_register_style('super-rss-reader-css', SRR_URL . 'public/srr-css.css');
 wp_enqueue_style('super-rss-reader-css');
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'srr_public_styles');

## Default color styles
$srr_color_styles = array(
 'No style' => 'none',
 'Grey' => 'grey',
 'Dark' => 'dark',
 'Orange' => 'orange',
 'Simple modern' => 'smodern'
);

## The main RSS Parser
function srr_rss_parser($instance){
 
 $urls = stripslashes($instance['urls']);
 $tab_titles = stripslashes($instance['tab_titles']);
 $count = intval($instance['count']);
 
 $show_date = intval($instance['show_date']);
 $show_desc = intval($instance['show_desc']);
 $show_author = intval($instance['show_author']);
 $show_thumb = stripslashes($instance['show_thumb']);
 $open_newtab = intval($instance['open_newtab']);
 $strip_desc = intval($instance['strip_desc']);
 $strip_title = intval($instance['strip_title']);
 $read_more = htmlspecialchars($instance['read_more']);
 $rich_desc = intval($instance['rich_desc']);
 
 $color_style = stripslashes($instance['color_style']);
 $enable_ticker = intval($instance['enable_ticker']);
 $visible_items = intval($instance['visible_items']);
 $ticker_speed = intval($instance['ticker_speed']) * 1000;
 
 if(empty($urls)){
  return '';
 }
 
 $rand = array();
 $url = explode(',', $urls);
 $tab_title = explode(',', $tab_titles);
 $ucount = count($url);
 
 // Generate the Tabs
 if($ucount > 1){
  echo '<ul class="srr-tab-wrap srr-tab-style-' . $color_style . ' srr-clearfix">';
  for( $i=0; $i < $ucount; $i++ ){
   // Get the Feed URL
   $feedUrl = trim( $url[$i] );
   $rss = fetch_feed( $feedUrl );
   $rand[$i] = rand(0, 999);
   
   if (!is_wp_error($rss)){
    
    if( isset( $tab_title[$i] ) && !empty( $tab_title[$i]) ){
     $rss_title = $tab_title[$i];
    }else{
     $rss_title = esc_attr(strip_tags($rss->get_title()));
    }
    
    echo '<li data-tab="srr-tab-' . $rand[$i] . '">' . $rss_title . '</li>';
   }else{
    echo '<li data-tab="srr-tab-' . $rand[$i] . '">Error</li>';
   }
   
  }
  echo '</ul>';
 }
 
 for($i=0; $i<$ucount; $i++){
  // Get the Feed URL
  $feedUrl = trim($url[$i]);
  if(isset($url[$i])){
   $rss = fetch_feed($feedUrl);
  }else{
   return '';
  }
  
  if( method_exists( $rss, 'enable_order_by_date' ) ){
   $rss->enable_order_by_date(false);
  }
  
  // Check for feed errors
  if (!is_wp_error( $rss ) ){
   $maxitems = $rss->get_item_quantity($count);
   $rss_items = $rss->get_items(0, $maxitems); 
   $rss_title = esc_attr(strip_tags($rss->get_title()));
   $rss_desc = esc_attr(strip_tags($rss->get_description()));
  }else{
   echo '<div class="srr-wrap srr-style-' . $color_style .'" data-id="srr-tab-' . $rand[$i] . '"><p>RSS Error: ' . $rss->get_error_message() . '</p></div>';
   continue;
  }
  
  $randAttr = isset($rand[$i]) ? ' data-id="srr-tab-' . $rand[$i] . '" ' : '';
  
  // Outer Wrap start
  echo '<div class="srr-wrap ' . (($enable_ticker == 1 ) ? 'srr-vticker' : '' ) . ' srr-style-' . $color_style . '" data-visible="' . $visible_items . '" data-speed="' . $ticker_speed . '"' . $randAttr . '><div>';
  
  // Check feed items
  if ($maxitems == 0){
   echo '<div>No items.</div>';
  }else{
   $j=1;
   // Loop through each feed item
   foreach ($rss_items as $item){
    // Get the link
    $link = $item->get_link();
    while ( stristr($link, 'http') != $link ){ $link = substr($link, 1); }
    $link = esc_url(strip_tags($link));
    
    // Get the item title
    $title = esc_attr(strip_tags($item->get_title()));
    if ( empty($title) )
     $title = __('No Title');
    
    if( $strip_title != 0 ){
     $titleLen = strlen($title);
     $title = wp_html_excerpt( $title, $strip_title );
     $title = ($titleLen > $strip_title) ? $title . ' ...' : $title;
    }
    
    // Open links in new tab
    $newtab = ($open_newtab) ? ' target="_blank"' : '';
    
    // Get the date
    $date = $item->get_date('j F Y');
    
    // Get thumbnail if present @since v2.2
    $thumb = '';
    if ($show_thumb == 1 && $enclosure = $item->get_enclosure()){
     $thumburl = $enclosure->get_thumbnail();
     if(!empty($thumburl))
     $thumb = '<img src="' . $thumburl . '" alt="' . $title . '" class="srr-thumb" align="left"/>';
    }
    
    // Get the description
    $desc = '';
    if( $rich_desc == 1 ){
    
     $desc = strip_tags( str_replace( 'eval', '', $item->get_description() ) , '<p><a><img><em><strong><font><strike><s><u><i>');

    }else{
    
     $desc = str_replace( array("\n", "\r"), ' ', esc_attr( strip_tags( @html_entity_decode( $item->get_description(), ENT_QUOTES, get_option('blog_charset') ) ) ) );
     if($strip_desc != 0){
      $desc = wp_html_excerpt( $desc, $strip_desc );
      $rmore = (!empty($read_more)) ?  '<a href="' . $link . '" title="Read more"' . $newtab . '>' . $read_more . '</a>' : '';
      
      if ( '[...]' == substr( $desc, -5 ) )
       $desc = substr( $desc, 0, -5 );
      elseif ( '[&hellip;]' != substr( $desc, -10 ) )
       $desc .= '';
       
      $desc = esc_html( $desc );
     }
     
     $desc = $thumb . $desc . ' ' . $rmore;
     
    }
        
    // Get the author
    $author = $item->get_author();
    if ( is_object($author) ) {
     $author = $author->get_name();
     $author = esc_html(strip_tags($author));
    }
  
    echo "\n\n\t";
    
    // Display the feed items
    echo '<div class="srr-item ' . (($j%2 == 0) ? 'even' : 'odd') . '">';
    echo '<div class="srr-title"><li><a href="' . $link . '"' . $newtab . ' title="Posted on ' . $date . '">' . $title . '</a></li></div>';
    echo '<div class="srr-meta">';
    
    if($show_date && !empty($date))
     echo '<time class="srr-date">' . $date . '</time>';
     
    if($show_author && !empty($author))
     echo ' - <cite class="srr-author">' . $author . '</cite>';
    
    echo '</div>';
    
    if($show_desc)
     echo '<p class="srr-summary srr-clearfix">' . $desc . '</p>';
     
    echo '</div>';
    // End display
    
    $j++;
   }
  }
  
  // Outer wrap end
  echo "\n\n</div>
  </div> \n\n" ;
  
  $rss->__destruct();
  unset($rss);
  
 }
}

class super_rss_reader_widget extends WP_Widget{
 ## Initialize
 function super_rss_reader_widget(){
  $widget_ops = array(
   'classname' => 'widget_super_rss_reader',
   'description' => "Enhanced RSS feed reader widget with advanced features."
  );
  
  $control_ops = array('width' => 430, 'height' => 500);
  parent::WP_Widget('super_rss_reader', 'Super RSS Reader', $widget_ops, $control_ops);
 }
 
 ## Display the Widget
 function widget($args, $instance){
  extract($args);
  if(empty($instance['title'])){
   $title = '';
  }else{
   $title = $before_title . apply_filters('widget_title', $instance['title'], $instance, $this->id_base) . $after_title;
  }
  
  echo $before_widget . $title;
  echo "\n" . '
  <!-- Start - Super RSS Reader v' . SRR_VERSION . '-->
  <div class="super-rss-reader-widget">' . "\n";
  
  srr_rss_parser($instance);
  
  echo "\n" . '</div>
  <!-- End - Super RSS Reader -->
  ' . "\n";
  echo $after_widget;
 }
 
 ## Save settings
 function update($new_instance, $old_instance){
  $instance = $old_instance;
  $instance['title'] = stripslashes($new_instance['title']);
  $instance['urls'] = stripslashes($new_instance['urls']);
  $instance['tab_titles'] = stripslashes($new_instance['tab_titles']);
  
  $instance['count'] = intval($new_instance['count']);
  $instance['show_date'] = intval($new_instance['show_date']);
  $instance['show_desc'] = intval($new_instance['show_desc']);
  $instance['show_author'] = intval($new_instance['show_author']);
  $instance['show_thumb'] = stripslashes($new_instance['show_thumb']);
  $instance['open_newtab'] = intval($new_instance['open_newtab']);
  $instance['strip_desc'] = intval($new_instance['strip_desc']);
  $instance['strip_title'] = intval($new_instance['strip_title']);
  $instance['read_more'] = stripslashes($new_instance['read_more']);
  $instance['rich_desc'] = stripslashes($new_instance['rich_desc']);
  
  $instance['color_style'] = stripslashes($new_instance['color_style']);
  $instance['enable_ticker'] = intval($new_instance['enable_ticker']);
  $instance['visible_items'] = intval($new_instance['visible_items']);
  $instance['ticker_speed'] = intval($new_instance['ticker_speed']);
  
  return $instance;
 }
 
 ## HJA Widget form
 function form($instance){
  global $srr_color_styles;
  
  $instance = wp_parse_args( (array) $instance, array(
   'title' => '', 'urls' => '', 'tab_titles' => '', 
   'count' => 5, 'show_date' => 0, 'show_desc' => 1, 
   'show_author' => 0, 'show_thumb' => 1, 'open_newtab' => 1, 
   'strip_desc' => 100, 'read_more' => '[...]', 'rich_desc' => 0 , 
   'color_style' => 'none', 'enable_ticker' => 1, 'visible_items' => 5, 
   'strip_title' => 0, 'ticker_speed' => 4,
  ));
  
  $title = htmlspecialchars($instance['title']);
  $urls = htmlspecialchars($instance['urls']);
  $tab_titles = htmlspecialchars($instance['tab_titles']);
  
  $count = intval($instance['count']);
  $show_date = intval($instance['show_date']);
  $show_desc = intval($instance['show_desc']);
  $show_author = intval($instance['show_author']);
  $show_thumb = intval($instance['show_thumb']);
  $open_newtab = intval($instance['open_newtab']);
  $strip_desc = intval($instance['strip_desc']);
  $strip_title = intval($instance['strip_title']);
  $read_more = htmlspecialchars($instance['read_more']);
  $rich_desc = htmlspecialchars($instance['rich_desc']);
  
  $color_style = stripslashes($instance['color_style']);
  $enable_ticker = intval($instance['enable_ticker']);
  $visible_items = intval($instance['visible_items']);
  $ticker_speed = intval($instance['ticker_speed']);
  
  ?>
  <div class="srr_settings">
  <table width="100%" height="72" border="0">
  <tr>
   <td width="13%" height="33"><label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('title'); ?>">Title: </label></td>
    <td width="87%"><input id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('title');?>" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name('title'); ?>" type="text" value="<?php echo $title; ?>" class="widefat"/></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td><label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('urls'); ?>">URLs: </label></td>
   <td><input id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('urls');?>" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name('urls'); ?>" type="text" value="<?php echo $urls; ?>" class="widefat"/>
   <small class="srr_smalltext">Can enter multiple RSS/atom feed URLs seperated by a comma.</small>
   </td>
  </tr>
  
  <tr>
   <td><label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('tab_titles'); ?>">Tab titles: </label></td>
   <td><input id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('tab_titles');?>" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name('tab_titles'); ?>" type="text" value="<?php echo $tab_titles; ?>" class="widefat"/>
   <small class="srr_smalltext">Enter corresponding tab titles seperated by a comma.</small>
   </td>
  </tr>
  
  </table>
  </div>
  
  <div class="srr_settings">
  <h4>Settings</h4>
  <table width="100%" border="0">
    <tr>
   <td width="7%" height="28"><input id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('show_desc'); ?>" type="checkbox"  name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name('show_desc'); ?>" value="1" <?php echo $show_desc == "1" ? 'checked="checked"' : ""; ?> /></td>
   <td width="40%"><label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('show_desc'); ?>">Show Description</label></td>
   <td width="28%"><label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('count');?>">Count</label></td>
   <td width="25%"><input id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('count');?>" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name('count'); ?>" type="text" value="<?php echo $count; ?>" class="widefat" title="No of feed items to parse"/></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
   <td height="32"><input id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('show_date'); ?>" type="checkbox"  name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name('show_date'); ?>" value="1" <?php echo $show_date == "1" ? 'checked="checked"' : ""; ?> /></td>
   <td><label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('show_date'); ?>">Show Date</label></td>
   <td><label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('strip_desc');?>">Strip description</label></td>
   <td><input id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('strip_desc');?>" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name('strip_desc'); ?>" type="text" value="<?php echo $strip_desc; ?>" class="widefat" title="The number of charaters to be displayed. Use 0 to disable stripping"/>   </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
   <td height="29"><input id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('show_author'); ?>" type="checkbox"  name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name('show_author'); ?>" value="1" <?php echo $show_author == "1" ? 'checked="checked"' : ""; ?> /></td>
   <td><label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('show_author'); ?>">Show Author</label></td>
   <td><label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('read_more'); ?>">Read more text</label></td>
   <td><input id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('read_more'); ?>" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name('read_more'); ?>" type="text" value="<?php echo $read_more; ?>" class="widefat" title="Leave blank to hide read more text"/></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td height="29"><input id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('open_newtab'); ?>" type="checkbox"  name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name('open_newtab'); ?>" value="1" <?php echo $open_newtab == "1" ? 'checked="checked"' : ""; ?> /></td>
      <td><label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('open_newtab'); ?>">Open links in new tab</label></td>
      <td><label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('strip_title'); ?>">Strip Title</label></td>
      <td><input id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('strip_title');?>" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name('strip_title'); ?>" type="text" value="<?php echo $strip_title; ?>" class="widefat" title="The number of charaters to be displayed. Use 0 to disable stripping"/></td>
       </tr>
    <tr>
      <td height="29"><input id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('show_thumb'); ?>" type="checkbox"  name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name('show_thumb'); ?>" value="1" <?php echo $show_thumb == "1" ? 'checked="checked"' : ""; ?> /></td>
      <td><label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('show_thumb'); ?>">Show thumbnail if present</label></td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
       </tr>
    
    <tr>
      <td height="29"><input id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('rich_desc'); ?>" type="checkbox"  name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name('rich_desc'); ?>" value="1" <?php echo $rich_desc == "1" ? 'checked="checked"' : ""; ?> /></td>
      <td><label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('rich_desc'); ?>">Enable full or rich description</label></td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
       </tr>
    
  </table>
  </div>
  
  <?php if( $rich_desc == 1 ): ?>
  <span class="srr_note">Note: You have enabled "Full/Rich HTML" Please make sure that the feed(s) are from trusted sources and do not contain any harmful scripts. If there are some aligment issues in the description, please use custom CSS to fix that. </span>
  <?php endif; ?>
  
  <div class="srr_settings">
  <h4>Other settings</h4>
  <table width="100%" height="109" border="0">
    <tr>
   <td height="32"><label>Color style: </label></td>
   <td>
   <?php
   echo '<select name="' . $this->get_field_name('color_style') . '" id="' . $this->get_field_id('color_style') . '">';
   foreach($srr_color_styles as $k => $v){
    echo '<option value="' . $v . '" ' . ($color_style == $v ? 'selected="selected"' : "") .  '>' . $k . '</option>';
   }
   echo '</select>';
   ?>
   </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
   <td height="33"><label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('enable_ticker'); ?>">Ticker animation:</label> </td>
   <td><input id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('enable_ticker'); ?>" type="checkbox"  name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name('enable_ticker'); ?>" value="1" <?php echo $enable_ticker == "1" ? 'checked="checked"' : ""; ?> /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
   <td height="36"><label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('visible_items');?>">Visible items: </label></td>
   <td><input id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('visible_items');?>" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name('visible_items'); ?>" type="text" value="<?php echo $visible_items; ?>" class="widefat" title="The no of feed items to be visible."/>
   </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
   <td height="36"><label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('ticker_speed');?>">Ticker speed: </label></td>
   <td><input id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('ticker_speed');?>" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name('ticker_speed'); ?>" type="text" value="<?php echo $ticker_speed; ?>" title="Speed of the ticker in seconds"/> seconds
   </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  </div>
  
  <div class="srr_support"> <a href="http://facebook.com/aakashweb" class="srr_fblike" target="_blank">Like</a> <a href="http://bit.ly/srrDonation" target="_blank" class="srr_donatebtn" title="If you like this plugin, then just make a small donation and it will be helpful for the plugin's development.">Donate</a> <a href="http://www.aakashweb.com/wordpress-plugins/super-rss-reader/" target="_blank">Support</a></div>
  <small>Please donate and share this plugin to show your support. Thank you :)</small>
  
  <?php
 }
}

function super_rss_reader_init(){
 register_widget('super_rss_reader_widget');
}
add_action('widgets_init', 'super_rss_reader_init');

function srr_widget_scripts(){
 if(in_array($GLOBALS['pagenow'], array('widgets.php'))){
 ?>
 <style type="text/css">
  .srr_settings h4{
   border-bottom: 1px solid #DFDFDF;
   margin: 20px -11px 10px -11px;
   padding: 5px 11px 5px 11px;
   border-top: 1px solid #DFDFDF;
   background-color: #fff;
   background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top,#fff,#f9f9f9);
   background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top,#fff,#f9f9f9);
   background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,#fff,#f9f9f9);
   background-image: linear-gradient(top,#fff,#f9f9f9);
  }
  .srr_smalltext{
   font-size: 11px;
   color: #666666;
  }
  .srr_support{
   border: 1px solid #DFDFDF;
   padding: 10px 13px;
   background: #F9F9F9;
   text-decoration: none;
   margin: 10px -13px;
  }
  .srr_support a{
   text-decoration: none;
   margin: 0 5px;
  }
  .srr_support a:hover{
   text-decoration: underline;
  }
  .srr_donatebtn{
   background: url('<?php echo SRR_URL;  ?>images/donate.png') left center no-repeat;
   color: #f60;
   padding-left: 20px;
  }
  .srr_fblike{
   background: url('<?php echo SRR_URL;  ?>images/like-button.png') left center no-repeat;
   padding-left: 19px;
  }
  .srr_fblike span{
   display: none;
  }
  .srr_fblike:hover span{
   display: inline;
   padding:10px;
   margin: -15px 0px 0px -50px;
   position:absolute;
   background:#ffffff;
   border:1px solid #cccccc;
   box-shadow: 0px 2px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.09);
   border-radius: 5px;
  }
  .srr_note{
   border: 1px solid #FFD893;
   padding: 5px;
   background: #FFFEDA;
   margin: 10px 0 0;
   display: block;
  }
 </style>
 
 <script type="text/javascript">
  jQuery(document).ready(function(){
   var social = '<iframe src="//www.facebook.com/plugins/like.php?href=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com%2Faakashweb&amp;send=false&amp;layout=button_count&amp;width=75&amp;show_faces=true&amp;action=like&amp;colorscheme=light&amp;font&amp;height=21&amp;appId=106994469342299" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" style="border:none; overflow:hidden; width:90px; height:21px;" allowTransparency="true"></iframe>';
   
   jQuery('.srr_fblike').live('mouseenter', function(){
    if(jQuery('.srr_fblike span').length == 0)
     jQuery(this).prepend('<span>' + social + '</span>');
   });
      
  });
 </script>
 
 <?php
 }
}
add_action('admin_footer', 'srr_widget_scripts');

?>
```

Comment: Could you not find the answer on the internet?

Comment: Correct, i had search but i not found soloution

Comment: http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2014/05/adding-c3po-connection-pooling-in-spring-jdbc.html